# How do I change my template so dynamic url works in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am making a dynamic URL in Django. These are the steps I followed:
First in `urls.py`

```
path('products/<int:my_id>/', views.products, name='products'),
```

Next, in `views.py` I added products view as defined below

```
def products(request, my_id, *args):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=my_id)
    custom_context = {
        'title': 'products',
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, 'products.html', custom_context)
```

then created its associated `products.html` file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Products Page</h1>
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
{{ object.price }}
{% endblock content%}
```

Once I type in addressbar something like `localhost:8000/products/1/` it shows this error page for me:
[image]

I wish the image is clear enough to see.
I saw that error and according to my solution I changed my structure of `products.html` file to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Products Page</h1>
    {{ object.title }}
    {{ object.description }}
    {{ object.price }}
</body>

</html>
```

then I saw it worked pretty fine as expected! which means that there are no problems in `urls.py`, `views.py` but only in my `.html` template. Can you please tell me what is the problem?
Thank you so much

edit:
base.html

```
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <span>LOGO</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links" id="sidenav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'products' %}">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'portfolio' %}">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'form' %}">Form</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burgers">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

edit: @sigdev

[image]

Comment: As you can *clearly* see in the error page, the problem is not coming from any of the code you have posted, but from the code in base.html.

Comment: yes sir, it is from base.html. I add the snippet of my HTML how do I solve it?

Comment: it seems to be a problem in here:
href="{% url 'products' %}" 
at my base.html

Comment: Yes. Because your "products" URL requires an ID parameter.

Comment: href="{% url 'products/<init:my_id>' %}"
and
href="{% url 'products/my_id/' %}"

Comment: sir, this gave me an error. Please edit that thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this mean url for **details** page of the product :

```
path('products/<int:my_id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

You should add url for **list** of product :

```
path('products/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
```

Then fix your products view for better understanding and name it **product_detail** view :

```
def product_detail(request, my_id, *args):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=my_id)
    custom_context = {
        'title': 'product_detail',
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', custom_context)
```

After you have to create your **product_list** view like :

```
def product_list(request, *args):
    object_list = Product.objects.all()
    custom_context = {
        'title': 'product_list',
        'object_list': object_list
    }
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', custom_context)
```

And for urls in template you have to call them like that:

```
<a href="{% url 'product_list' %}">Product List</a>
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' my_id=object.id %}">Product Details for product {{ object.id }} </a>
```

Comment: yet I didn't create another link for product details, but I manipulate my base.html as you said and added this 
<a href="{% url 'products' my_id=object.id %}">dforPro: {{ object.id }} </a>

Comment: it still shows the error, I added a screenshot of the error above in my code

Comment: I just told you all the things you should fix. It will not work if you just fix one thing...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two separate urls and views, one for the general products listing page (for all products), and the other for the specific product page.

```
path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
path('product/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.product, name='product'),
```

Comment: yes, that is true but there is a problem in my base.html

Comment: Your base.html needs to have one link to the 'products' url (the general products page), without the my_id parameter, because you aren't referring to any specific product.  Then the products page should have a listing of all the individual product urls.  Or you could put all the individual product urls in your base template by adding all your product urls to a global context processor for use on every page.

Comment: Now I get the point, why I need to have two separate pages. but please edit the why this url is throwing an error after even creating two pages: 

            <li><a href="{% url 'product_list' %}">Product List</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'product_detail' my_id=object.id %}">Product Details for product {{ object.id }}</a>
            </li>

Comment: sorry, it can't be read properly, but hopefully you can see what is goin on there